# Map downsampled image to original resolution - MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, pixel

I have a small 3D image (500x1000x100) and would like to downsample to 1% of the pixels. I would then like to map this back to a binary (true/false, 1/0) of the same original dimensions, where the relative positions of the downsampled pixels are 1 and everything else is 0.

So maybe like:

```
small_im = imresize(im,0.01);
%create some sort of mapping
binary_tensor = %true wherever the downsampled image's pixels are present,       
                %relatively speaking. But of the same dims as im
```

EDIT:
Think of a 100x100 image. downsample it to 10x10. take every pixel in that downsample and map it back to the original dimensions and let them be TRUE in a binary tensor of the same dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is divisible by 100 (or can be multiplied by 1%),

```
small_im=im(1:100:end,1:100:end,1:100:end);

mask=false(size(im));
mask(1:100:end,1:100:end,1:100:end)=true;
```

Comment: The actual image file right now is 512x1024x100. And there are many more of varying dimensions.

This looks great, but may lose some details when I get to images with dims such as 3194x1041x658

Comment: Also, when I call sum(sum(sum(mask(:,:,:)))) I get 66, but I believe it should be closer to 500k considering we are selecting all the pixels from a 99% downsample of a 50mil element array

Comment: @Alex there are things here I might have misunderstood: 1) I am selecting the 1% that has been used in the downsampled image, not 99%. 2) If you downample to a rate that is not divisible by the ratio, you need to interpolate. For your question to make sense in this case you need to define the interpolation method and how you want to select "partial" pixels that would be used in the downampling

Comment: Sure, let me try to explain it better. I want to resize the image by a factor of n, n=0.01 here: `small_im = imresize(im,0.01,'nearest);` and then take all the pixels from small_im and map them to a logical/binary array with the same dimensions as the original image. This logical array should be true at cells where it maps to the relative location of a pixel from small_im and false otherwise. I expect to have 1% of the pixels in this 3d logical array to be true.  




Thanks for the help and let me know if this makes sense

Comment: @Alex my answer does exactly that for multipliers of 0.01. I will try to update for general nearest neighbours.